# How to test mobile apps performance

Tags: android, performance, testing, mobile, cordova

I am working on a student project, and I have to test mobile application performance of user interface (how long does it take to load user interface), getting data from database (when connected to wireless connection, when connected to 3G/4G), battery efficiency (how much buttery does the application consume, and how long will battery last when running this application).....

There are two versions of the app, one is developed with android framework, the other with [mobile framework](http://phonegap.com/), I need a program which allows mobile application performance testing, can you help me?

Does standard DDMS which comes with android sdk provide this information?

Answer (score 0):

I've found Android's [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) utility to work well for overall performance testing.  You can either use it in the Monitor tool that comes with the sdk or use it in the DDMS Perspective in Eclipse.  With the standalone version from the link I was able to place start and end points in the areas that I wanted to profile but I'm not sure if you are to do that with these versions.

As far as the battery life goes there was a [Google I/O presentation](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/CodingLifeBatteryLife.html) a while back that should help you out.  It goes into how to design for preserving battery life and gives ideas on how to test it.